# need regular expression to remove brackets

Tags: python, regex

I newbie in python.  I have an array `[' [59342486', '59343079]']`. I would like to 
write a regular expression that get rid of the brackets inside 
`' [59342486'
'59343079]'`

would you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance 
Jean

Comment: You don't need a regular expression. Just use the string `replace()` method.

Comment: also, regex doesn't *remove* the brackets. It will help you *find* the brackets to be removed.

Comment: Where did you even get this weird list? The code that builds this list probably needs to be fixed, perhaps by using `ast.literal_eval` or by avoiding a conversion to strings at some point before here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` for this:

```
for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
  my_list[index] = item.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
```

Comment: Actually neither `while` nor `if` are needed. By default `replace` replaces every instance  of the required character. The problem is that it is not in-place, thus your example won't work as expected.

Comment: You don't need a `while` loop. the `replace()` method will remove all occurrences of the substring.

Answer (score 4):

```
 new_list = [s.replace('[','').replace(']','') for s in old_list]
```

If you'd like to remove leading and trailing whitespace:

```
new_list = [s.replace('[','').replace(']','').strip() for s in old_list]
```

You can also do it in place:

```
old_list[:] = [s.replace('[','').replace(']','') for s in old_list]
```

Comment: This is nice, and the OP didn't ask for it, but it leaves the leading space in the first item of the list.  I'm guessing that could cause problems later, so maybe chain `.strip()` to the expression